# How to modify the button width and height in ActionCell of GWT

Tags: gwt

the button is automatically generated by the ActionCell in gwt, I want to change the width and height of the generated button, any method?
I chekced the ActionCell has no any addStyleName to allow me to change the css of the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options.

If you use this cell in a CellTable or DataGrid, set the style on a column which is built using ActionCell:

```
myColumn.setCellStyleNames("myButtonStyle");
```

You can also set this style on the parent element which includes ActionCell:

```
.myButtonStyle button {
    background: red;
}
```

or, even more specific, if necessary:

```
.myButtonStyle td button {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: yes, I can modify the height and width of the button in the actionCell using  
    myColumn.setCellStyleNames("myButtonStyle");  
as you mention, but I cannot modify the font-size of the button, using   
    .myButtonStyle button{
      height: 10px;
      width: 20px;
      font-size: 10px;
    }  
or  
    .myButtonStyle {  
      font-size:10px;  
    }

Comment: Try font-size: 10px !important;